# Custom shapes doesn't work when Tableau dashboard is published on the Tableau Server 10.1

Tags: tableau-api

I have used some custom shapes on the tableau dashboard. It looks perfect on the desktop but doesn't work when it's published on the Tableau Server 10.1.1, which is running on Windows 2012 R2. I see some weird default shapes on the dash though.

I couldn't find the Tableau repository directory on the server hence not sure where to upload them.

Comment: You don't need to do on server just create a sheet with custom shape and upload on tableau server. To get your shapes in tableau desktop save your all shape in this directory "..\Documents\My Tableau Repository\Shapes"

Comment: Did you check the box to include external files when you published?

Comment: Hi @AlexBlakemore,

I'm sorry, I'm not sure if I have understood your query. I created the directory My Tableau Repository > Shapes > My Shapes on the server as the entire directory structure was missing on it and then uploaded the images I created but it still didn't work.

Comment: Hi @MehulKatara,

I have got the Tableau server upgraded to the latest version as available today but it didn't work.

When I publish the workbook, it shows some default shapes on the server and moreover, it removes the shapes from my desktop dash as well. So I guess something weird happens when it syncs with the server.

Any suggestions, please?

Comment: Just found another bug, it doesn't even recognize it's shapes given under the other categories like Filled, Arrows, Proportion and so on. Whatever category and shape I choose, it just reverts back to Default category automatically.

Again, any help please

Comment: When you publish your workbook from Tableau Desktop, you get prompted to answer questions, about the name, site, project, permissions etc. under "other options', it will ask whether to show tabs. Do you see a checkbox called 'Include External Files'? Try clicking it

Comment: Yes, that option is ticked. Also, as I mentioned above, after the worksheet is published, the shapes get automatically changed to "Default" shapes. That said, the desktop and the server, both shows the default shapes. It doesn't even recognise it's own shapes given under different (built in) categories.

Comment: @anuj Before you publish workbook check include external files

Comment: Hi @MehulKatara

The issue was due to formula being directly used in the Shape Shelf instead of Calculated Field. I should have the scenario at first place.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Calculated field should be used instead of using formula directly in the Shapes Shelf.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

I have tried and working in Tableau Server Version: 10.2.1.

To get your shapes in tableau desktop save your all shape in this directory

"..\Documents\My Tableau Repository\Shapes"

Before you publish workbook check include external files

[image]

Comment: Thanks heaps Mehul. 
So in short this seems a bug in 10.1?
I will ask him to do the necessary upgrade from 10.1 to 10.2.

Comment: @anuj Before you publish workbook check include external files

Comment: @Anuj  if the answer is helpful then https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: Hi @Mehul, don't have voting privilege but have marked below answer as correct one as I had included the external files but it worked only when I used calculated field